# Unable to create bundle in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, gradle, flutter-dependencies

I am building a flutter project using Gradle. When I ran

```
flutter build appbundle
```

I got the error as shown below

```
 FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.                              
 
                                                                         
 * What went wrong:                                                       Execution failed for task ':image_gallery_saver:compileReleaseKotlin'.
 
 > Kotlin could not find the required JDK tools in the Java installation '/Library/Internet
 Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin/Contents/Home' used by Gradle. Make
 sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE.
                                                                         
 * Try:                                                                   Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info
 or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full
 insights.
                                                                         
 * Get more help at https://help.gradle.org                              
                                                                          BUILD FAILED in 24s                                                   
 Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'...                                
 Running Gradle task 'bundleRelease'... Done                       
 25.7s Gradle task bundleRelease failed with exit code 1
```

Please help me regarding this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

> Make sure Gradle is running on a JDK, not JRE

You are running gradle on a JRE instead of a JDK, install JDK 16 or below (17 is not supported yet), append its bin directory to the `PATH` variable and remove the one of the JRE.

Comment: Thanks for the response, could you also guide to check JDK or JRE version and configure the same?

Comment: You should not use a JRE. Download JDK 16.0.1 (If you're using Windows) [here](https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk16.0.1/7147401fd7354114ac51ef3e1328291f/9/GPL/openjdk-16.0.1_windows-x64_bin.zip)